# Modify each occurrence of regular expression match

Tags: python, regex

I have a string that I'd like to parse and modify certain substrings that match a regular expression.

The text I need to parse is a mixture of text and `<img>` tags surrounded by `<a>` tags and i need to strip out the entire `<a>` tag and replace it with a modified version of the src attribute of the `<img>` tag. The following code does a good job of getting the src attribute but only returns me a list of the regular expressions matching substrings which is not much use without knowing the positions where the match was found.

```
print re.findall('<a.+><img.+src="(.+?)".+/></a>', sample_text)
```

(I'm aware that this re isn't bullet proof but it does for this job)

Whats the best way to achieving the desired effect?

Example input:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/test.png"><img src="http://www.example.com/test.png" /></a>

Bla blabla

<a href="http://www.example.com/test.png"><img src="http://www.example.com/test.png" /></a>
bla bla bla
```

Desired output:

```
<div><img src="http://www.different_domain.com/images/test.png" /><div>

Bla blabla

<div><img src="http://www.different_domain.com/images/test.png" /></div>
bla bla bla
```

Comment: Do you have some example data - Input and desired output?

Comment: good point, just added some

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.sub` to do replacement:

```
>>> string = '''<a href="http://www.example.com/test.png"><img src="http://www.example.com/test.png" /></a>

Bla blabla

<a href="http://www.example.com/test.png"><img src="http://www.example.com/test.png" /></a>
bla bla bla'''
>>> print re.sub(r'<a.*><img(.+)src="(.+?)(\/[^\/]+)"(.*/?)></a>', r'<div><img\1src="http://different-domain.com/images\3"\4></div>', string)
<div><img src="http://different-domain.com/images/test.png" /></div>

Bla blabla

<div><img src="http://different-domain.com/images/test.png" /></div>
bla bla bla
```

You probably want to capture more groups, but I think this is the gist of what you're looking for